# how to make chat application using signalR in asp.net 3.5

Tags: signalr, asp.net-3.5

i just want to make one chatting enabled web site that all users can chat with each other. how ever i just found SignalIR was useful for that. but hoe ever how it integrate with asp.net 3.5. how ever i think it's only works with framework 4.0. is that other alternative that gives me SignalIR feature.

Comment: You may not have the requirement for signalR yet, look for Long Polling. Anways the singalR would downgrade to Long Polling if requirements are not met (i.e. HTML5 support on browser, and support for web sockets). Hope this helps.

Comment: there's no "I" in SignalR, it's a group effort!

Comment: @ShashankChaturvedi - can u give me best articles for chat application  with using HTML5 and Web sockets.